# Python Minus and Plus Functions reversed?

Tags: python, numbers, calculator

Today i installed python and i was curious about this one. I created this small "Calculator" thing, if you can even call it that...

```
first_number = input("First Number: ")
second_number = input("Second Number: ")
sign = input("Sign: ")
difference = int(first_number) + int(second_number)
summary = int(first_number) - int(second_number)



if not sign.find("-"):
    print(summary)
if sign.find("-"):
    print(difference)
```

and it works... when you insert "-" as a sign it does num1 - num2

**MY QUESTION IS:**

WHY DOES THIS

```
difference = int(first_number) + int(second_number)
summary = int(first_number) - int(second_number)
```

WORK???
Difference part is working and printing correctly (num1 - num2) even though it contains "+" Sign between numbers???

Comment: Huh? please show an exact [mcve] including the input you provide and the output you get

Comment: @DeepSpace I just tried it; when I input first number 3 and second number 2, with + I get 5, and with - I get 1.

Comment: I meant to say IT DOES WORK. I just want to know why is that part where i define "summary" and "difference" working the opposite way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's `.find` function returns the index in the string that the character is found. Here, if you pass in the string `'-'`, it will return 0, as the character `-` is found at the 0th index.

When evaluating True/False statements, Python evaluates `0` as `False`. This means that for `sign='-'`, your code will print `summary`.

To fix this, use `in` or an equality instead. For example:

```
if sign == '-':
 <do this>

OR

if '-' in sign:
 <do this>
```

Comment: i thought it was a like feature lol, my bad

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code, with 'print' statements under your 'if' statements like this:

```
first_number = input("First Number: ")
second_number = input("Second Number: ")
sign = input("Sign: ")
difference = int(first_number) + int(second_number)
summary = int(first_number) - int(second_number)



if not sign.find("-"):
    print('summary')
    print(summary)
if sign.find("-"):
    print('difference')
    print(difference)
```

You can see which value the program is returning. Does this help at all?